# Know if const qualifier is used

Tags: c, constants

Is there any way in C to find if a variable has the const qualifier? Or if it's stored in the .rodata section?

For example, if I have this function:

```
void foo(char* myString) {...}
```

different actions should be taken in these two different function calls:

```
char str[] = "abc";
foo(str);

foo("def");
```

In the first case I can modify the string, in the second one no.

Comment: In the first case you COULD modify the string, but you MUST NOT. If you want a mutable string, use initialization instead of assignment. For example: `char str[] = "abc";`.

Comment: Ok you are right. It was only an (incorrect) example!

Comment: what's your use case here? smells like bad design to me...

Comment: Anyway, in C `"def"` *doesn't* have the const qualifier, array literals are non-const arrays. It's just allowed to be in read-only data because you're not allowed to modify it.

Comment: I can't think of a good reason for needing to do this...

Answer (score 4):

Not in standard C, i.e. not portably.

`myString` is just a `char*` in `foo`, all other information is lost. Whatever you feed into the function is automatically converted to `char*`.

And C does not know about "`.rodata`".

Depending on your platform you could check the address in `myString` (if you know your address ranges).

Comment: Check the address seems to be the exact opposite of compatibility! :D

Comment: @Dario: Compatibility? You mean portability? Yes. It is not portable. As I wrote, there is no portable solution.

Answer (score 2):

GCC provides the [`__builtin_constant_p`](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gcc/gcc_81.html) builtin function, which enables you to determine whether an expression is constant or not at compile-time:

> Built-in Function: int __builtin_constant_p (exp)
>
> You can use the built-in function __builtin_constant_p to determine if a value is known to be constant at compile-time and hence that GCC can perform constant-folding on expressions involving that value. The argument of the function is the value to test. The function returns the integer 1 if the argument is known to be a compile-time constant and 0 if it is not known to be a compile-time constant. A return of 0 does not indicate that the value is not a constant, but merely that GCC cannot prove it is a constant with the specified value of the `-O' option.

So I guess you should rewrite your `foo` function as a macro in such a case:

```
#define foo(x) \
  (__builtin_constant_p(x) ? foo_on_const(x) : foo_on_var(x))
```

`foo("abc")` would expand to `foo_on_const("abc")` and `foo(str)` would expand to `foo_on_var(str)`.

Comment: The case in question cannot be solved at compile time, so `__builtin_constant_p` won't help here, right?

Comment: Thanks for the tip but I was looking for a run-time method. :(

Comment: The macro will only detect a `const` correctly in the most basic case: when a `const` is given as argument to `foo` directly. As soon as `foo`'s argument is an argument of the calling function, this won't work. Besides, shouldn't we rather check if the not-necessarily-constant pointer is pointing to a `const`?

Answer (score 2):

You can't differ them using the language alone. In other words, this is not possible without recurring to features specific to the compiler you're using, which is likely not to be portable. A few important remarks though:

In the first case you COULD modify the string, but you MUST NOT. If you want a mutable string, use *initialization* instead of *assignment*.

```
char *str1 = "abc"; // NOT OK, should be const char *
const char *str2 = "abc"; // OK, but not mutable
char str3[] = "abc"; // OK, using initialization, you can change its contents
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#include<stdio.h>
void foo(char *mystr)
{
int a;
/*code goes here*/   


#ifdef CHECK
int local_var;
printf(" strings address %p\n",mystr);
printf("local variables address %p \n",&local_var);
puts("");
puts("");
#endif
return;
}
int main()
{
char a[]="hello";
char *b="hello";
foo(a);
foo(b);
foo("hello");
}
```

On compiling with gcc -DCHECK prog_name.c and executing on my linux machine the following output comes...

```
strings address 0xbfdcacf6
local variables address 0xbfdcacc8 


strings address 0x8048583
local variables address 0xbfdcacc8 


strings address 0x8048583
local variables address 0xbfdcacc8
```

for first case when string is defined and initialized in the "proper c way for mutable strings" the difference between the addresses is 0x2E.(5 bytes).

in the second case when string is defined as char *p="hello" the differences in addresses is 
0xB7D82745.Thats bigger than the size of my stack.so i am pretty sure the string is not on the stack.Hence the only place where you can find it is .rodata section.

The third one is similar case

PS:As mentioned above this isn't portable but the original question hardly leaves any scope for portability by mentioning **.rodata** :)

Comment: Try it with `char c[] = "foo";` outside of `main`.

Comment: thats when it goes into the .data section.I am aware of that.I assumed the variables were local.Though I should have mentioned it.Apologies for that