# How to check if a string is constant - C

Tags: c, string, constants

How do I check if a string is a constant?

Like `const char *name;`

I want to check if name is a constant in the C language.

How would I do that?

Comment: Um. you're variable declaration already *tells* you what it points to its constant as far as its usage is concerned. If you're wondering whether there is a standard-conforming way that, given some valid pointer passed to you as a `const char*` you can determine whether it is the address of a writable array vs a read-only literal, no such facility exists (and thats a good thing, or it would be severely abused).

Comment: I'm assuming you would want this for different code paths for constants.  For compiler specific versions see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Object-Size-Checking.html#Object-Size-Checking

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to check it in run-time - it is not possible in C language. On the other hand during compile time compiler will report error if you want to reassign a constant variable to some value.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, you actually can't check if a variable is constant because const is a compile-time concept that can be cast away.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8151181/know-if-const-qualifier-is-used) you can see some more details.