# How to check if a variable is of "const" qualifier type in C?

Tags: c, gcc, constants

Sample code to check

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    const int i = 1;
    printf("Variable i is %s\n",
           __builtin_constant_p(i) ? "a const variable" : "not a const variable");
    return 0;
}
```

Output :

```
Variable i is not a const variable
```

Is `__builtin_constant_p()` not the right API to determine whether a variable is of type `const` or not?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Know if const qualifier is used](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8151181/know-if-const-qualifier-is-used)

Comment: Why do a run-time check for something which is known at compile time? I'm not sure if there is any portable way to do what you want since C doesn't support run-time type introspection.

Comment: @MooingDuck It is C code. How did you say it is cpp?

Comment: `__builtin_constant_p` detects a *constant expression*, which is different to a `const`-qualified variable. E.g. try `const int i = argc;`, it will say non-const.

Comment: @smead that thread is mainly asking about whether it can be determined if a char array is mutable or not  (it's badly titled), I wouldn't say that this thread is a duplicate of that

Comment: @mk.. I thought `include` with angle brackets was C++ only, but a quick check shows that's C as well. My bad. C code it is.

Comment: Looks like an XY problem to me. C is statically typed. 1) This only makes sense for a macro. In a function you already know the type of an object. 2) Hiding different behaviour (why else would one test for `const`?) in a macro results in confusion, as one has to know how the macro behaves for each call. Better use different functions, whoever invokes the macro **will know** the full type (including `const`ness) of the object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Generic selection (since C11):

```
#include <stdio.h> 

#define __is_constant_int(X) _Generic((&X), \
        const int *: "a const int", \
        int *:       "a non-const int")

int main(void)
{
    const int i = 1;
    printf("Variable i is %s\n", __is_constant_int(i));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The standard is defective and doesn't say whether `i` should match `int` or `const int` here. See [N1930](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1930.htm) for discussion. I have edited to a version that works

Comment: @M.M, this DR is about to be resolved, and indeed the intent of the comittee was to have a type as if it had undergone "lvalue conversion" and thus qualifiers dropped. So the original version wouldn't work and the one after your edit works.

Comment: This still will be evaluated at compile-time. While I see good use in generic functions for various size-types but identical _behaviour_, this hides a completely different behaviour. Looks like a good way to confusion for the next reader/maintainer.

Comment: @Olaf This format should be more helpful to avoid "hiding a completely different behaviour"

Comment: @sunqingyao: If you have to check for `const` qualifier, there is obviously different behaviour intendend. `_Generic` only makes sense in a macro, as you otherwise know the full type of the object you use. See my extended answer for details. Assuming the `printf` is just an example for processing code, it definitively hides different semantics.

Answer (score 3):

[RTFineManual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.3/gcc/Other-Builtins.html#Other-Builtins):

> You can use the built-in function __builtin_constant_p to determine if a value is known to be **constant at compile time** ..."

(emphasis mine) Note this is a gcc compiler extension, thus not standard compliant.

C does not have symbolic constants other than *enum-constants*. `const` qualified objects are still variables. Thus the test fails. See the manual for a typical application.

---

**Notes:**

Assuming the code shown is just an example, your question looks like an XY-problem. C is statically typed, thus at the point you use such a construct the full type is well known. The only way to have something function-like would be a macro. But hiding different behaviour in a macro will cause confusion by the reader of the code. She has to remember this difference for every invokation.

Instead use two functions with the different behaviour and name them accordingly.  As the caller know the type he can use the correct function and any reader of the code (including you some weeks later!) will instantly know about the difference.

Answer (score 0):

For `GCC`/`LLVM` you can use `__builtin_types_compatible_p`,
`__builtin_choose_expr`, and `__builtin_classify_type` to do this
**generically without having to make a case for each pointer type**. The only drawback is you need to
explicitly check all nested levels (i.e you need a seperate macro for
`T const * const *` and `T const **` so it will be painful to code
past double-triple nested).

### Solution

```
// GCC / LLVM support __builtin_classify_type.
#define is_p(x)                                                                \
    (__builtin_classify_type(as_not_void(x)) == 5 /* 5 is ptr type.  */)

/* GCC does not const evaluate `__builtin_classify_type` if `x` is void.  */
#define as_not_void(x)                                                         \
    (__builtin_choose_expr(__builtin_types_compatible_p(__typeof__(x), void),  \
                           0, (x)))

// Choose never const pointer if `x` is not a pointer. This allows us to
// compiler `*(x)` when building the constant types.
#define as_ptr(x) (__builtin_choose_expr(is_p(x), (x), ((void **)(NULL))) + 0)

// Rebuild `T *` -> `T const *`
#define make_kp(x) __typeof__(*as_ptr(x)) const *

// Rebuild `T **` -> `T const **`
#define make_kpp(x) __typeof__(*as_ptr(*as_ptr(x))) const **

// Rebuild `T **` -> `T const * const *`
#define make_kpkp(x) __typeof__(*as_ptr(*as_ptr(x))) const * const *


#define build_kp_checker(macro, x)                                             \
    __builtin_types_compatible_p(macro(x), __typeof__(as_ptr(x)))

// API
// Is `x` T const *
#define is_kp(x) build_kp_checker(make_kp, x)

// Is `x` T const **
#define is_kpp(x) build_kp_checker(make_kpp, x)

// Is `x` T const * const *
#define is_kpkp(x) build_kp_checker(make_kpkp, x)
```

The general idea is if `x` is a pointer type, we rebuild it as
whatever degree of `const` pointers we want to check and use
`__builtin_types_compatible` to see if we rebuilt the same type or a
new one.

The solution about will check all cases for single/double nested
pointers. It will unfortunately take 4 additional macros to do triple
and 8 after that to do quadruple. It will still compile if you pass it a triple nested pointer, but it won't be able to recognize a pattern like `T const * const * const *` and different from `T const * const *`.

### Test

```
#define _stringify(X) #X
#define stringify(X)  _stringify(X)

#define is_const(x) __builtin_constant_p(x)
#define const_ptr_info(T)                                                      \
    {                                                                          \
        T _tmp;                                                                \
        printf("\n%-24s: is_kp=%d(%d), is_kpp=%d(%d), is_kpkp=%d(%d)\n",       \
               stringify(T), is_kp(_tmp), is_const(is_kp(_tmp)), is_kpp(_tmp), \
               is_const(is_kpp(_tmp)), is_kpkp(_tmp),                          \
               is_const(is_kpkp(_tmp)));                                       \
    }

#define const_ptr_info_arr(T)                                                  \
    {                                                                          \
        T _tmp[4];                                                             \
        printf("\n%-24s: is_kp=%d(%d), is_kpp=%d(%d), is_kpkp=%d(%d)\n",       \
               stringify(T), is_kp(_tmp), is_const(is_kp(_tmp)), is_kpp(_tmp), \
               is_const(is_kpp(_tmp)), is_kpkp(_tmp),                          \
               is_const(is_kpkp(_tmp)));                                       \
    }

typedef struct do_structs_work {
    char a;
    int  b;
} do_structs_work_t;

typedef struct do_unions_work {
    char a;
    int  b;
} do_unions_work_t;


int
main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    printf("\n----Testing Non-ptrs----\n");
    const_ptr_info(int);
    const_ptr_info(const int);
    printf("\n----Testing Structs----\n");
    const_ptr_info(do_structs_work_t);
    const_ptr_info(do_unions_work_t);

    printf("\n----Testing double points----\n");
    const_ptr_info(void **);
    const_ptr_info(const void **);

    const_ptr_info(void const **);
    const_ptr_info(void const * const *);

    printf("\n----Testing single pointers----\n");
    const_ptr_info(void * const *);
    const_ptr_info(void *);
    const_ptr_info(void const *);
    const_ptr_info(void * const);
    const_ptr_info(const void *);

    const_ptr_info(int *);
    const_ptr_info(int const *);
    const_ptr_info(int * const);

    printf("\n----Testing Arrays----\n");
    const_ptr_info_arr(int const);
    const_ptr_info_arr(int);
    const_ptr_info_arr(int const *);
    const_ptr_info_arr(int * const);
}
```

Yields:

```
----Testing Non-ptrs----

int                     : is_kp=0(1), is_kpp=0(1), is_kpkp=0(1)

const int               : is_kp=0(1), is_kpp=0(1), is_kpkp=0(1)

----Testing Structs----

do_structs_work_t       : is_kp=0(1), is_kpp=0(1), is_kpkp=0(1)

do_unions_work_t        : is_kp=0(1), is_kpp=0(1), is_kpkp=0(1)

----Testing double points----

void **                 : is_kp=0(1), is_kpp=0(1), is_kpkp=0(1)

const void **           : is_kp=0(1), is_kpp=1(1), is_kpkp=0(1)

void const **           : is_kp=0(1), is_kpp=1(1), is_kpkp=0(1)

void const * const *    : is_kp=1(1), is_kpp=0(1), is_kpkp=1(1)

----Testing single pointers----

void * const *          : is_kp=1(1), is_kpp=0(1), is_kpkp=0(1)

void *                  : is_kp=0(1), is_kpp=0(1), is_kpkp=0(1)

void const *            : is_kp=1(1), is_kpp=0(1), is_kpkp=0(1)

void * const            : is_kp=0(1), is_kpp=0(1), is_kpkp=0(1)

const void *            : is_kp=1(1), is_kpp=0(1), is_kpkp=0(1)

int *                   : is_kp=0(1), is_kpp=0(1), is_kpkp=0(1)

int const *             : is_kp=1(1), is_kpp=0(1), is_kpkp=0(1)

int * const             : is_kp=0(1), is_kpp=0(1), is_kpkp=0(1)

----Testing Arrays----

int const               : is_kp=1(1), is_kpp=0(1), is_kpkp=0(1)

int                     : is_kp=0(1), is_kpp=0(1), is_kpkp=0(1)

int const *             : is_kp=0(1), is_kpp=1(1), is_kpkp=0(1)

int * const             : is_kp=1(1), is_kpp=0(1), is_kpkp=0(1)
```

Which is what we want.

Answer (score 0):

> How to check if a variable is of "const" qualifier type in C?

With GCC you can do this:

```
#define IS_CONST(x) \
    __builtin_types_compatible_p( \
        __typeof__(x)*, \
        const __typeof__(x)* )
```

`__builtin_types_compatible_p` ignores top level qualifiers, but these are pointers.

> Is __builtin_constant_p() not the right API to determine whether a variable is of type const or not?

No, `__builtin_constant_p` checks if the *value* of the expression is known at compile time, not is the type if `const` qualified.

Answer (score 0):

Fully generically with the newly standardized `typeof` (which has been long supported by many (gcc, clang, tinycc) compilers):

```
#define ISCONST(Lval) _Generic(&(Lval), typeof(Lval) const*: 1, default: 0) 
//the ptr-indirection gets around _Generic's 
//rvalue (top-level-qualifier dropping) conversion

//TEST:
int const x = 42; int  y = 43;
_Static_assert(ISCONST(x) && !ISCONST(y),"");
```